# Can't move .dll to executible with post build commands

Tags: c++, lua

So I am rather new to working on larger projects. I am trying to use premake5 to generate the projects and solutions for Visual Studio 2019

This is what I have in my premake lua file

```
    workspace "DragonHeart"
    architecture "x64"
    startproject "Sandbox"
    
    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }
    
outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"
    
project "DragonHeart"
    location "DragonHeart"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"
    
    targetdir ("bin" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    
    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }
    
    includedirs
    {
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/spdlog/include"
    }
    
    
    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++14"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"
        
        defines
        {
            "DH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
            "DH_BUILD_DLL"
        }
        
        postbuildcommands
        {
            {"{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox"}
        }
        
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "DH_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"
    
    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "DH_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"
        
    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "DH_DIST"
        optimize "On"
        
project "Sandbox"
    
    location "Sandbox"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    
    targetdir ("bin" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    
    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }
    
    includedirs
    {
        "DragonHeart/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "DragonHeart/src"
    }
    
    links
    {
        "DragonHeart"
    }
    
    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++14"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"
        
        defines
        {
            "DH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS"
        }
        
        
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "DH_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"
    
    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "DH_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"
        
    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "DH_DIST"
        optimize "On"
```

My problem is when I run and try to build things VS2019 runs into an issue with the post build.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "IF EXIST ..\binDebug-windows-x86_64\DragonHeart\DragonHeart.dll\ (xcopy /Q /E /Y /I ..\binDebug-windows-x86_64\DragonHeart\DragonHeart.dll ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox > nul) ELSE (xcopy /Q /Y /I ..\binDebug-windows-x86_64\DragonHeart\DragonHeart.dll ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox > nul)
:VCEnd" exited with code 2. DragonHeart C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 155
```

I am not sure why it is not working. I know that there is a \ after the .dll but manually removing it does not change anything. And I think that exit code 2 means it could not find the file but comparing the file path with what is actually there it looks like it should find it. I have no idea how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ended up figuring out the problem. I changed {CODE} to {CODEFILE} and I didn't notice that the directory output was incorrect being bin/Debug... instead of binDebug...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I fixed it by putting the postbuildcommands in the Sandbox project and changing the directories of the copy instruction.
You should add this in the windows filter of the Sandbox project and remove the postbuildcommands from the DragonHeart project

```
    postbuildcommands
    {
        "{COPY} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/DragonHeart/*.dll ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox"
    }
```

I don't know why the other code doesn't work but this seems to bypass the problem